# Magento soap api version1 get list of closed orders

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

We would like to get the list of closed orders by passing from and to date filter in magento soap api.

Help me great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i pass the parameters like below, its working:

```
    $params = array('filter' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' => 'closed'
                ),
            ),'complex_filter'=>
    array(
        array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'from','value' => '2013-03-20 01:01:01'))
    ),
    array(
        array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'to','value' => 2019-03-20 01:01:01))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please test with below filters which is done with status and create_at filter :

> /rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=complete&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-02-29%2017:12:00&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

Comment: Hi @mansuri not by rest api ts by soap api

Comment: Hi @mansuri any help??

Comment: i m looking for something.

Comment: Thanks for spending ur time on that, please let me know if anything found